# How should execute/run be defined for my serverinfo.js for discord.js

Tags: discord.js, typeerror, execute

This is the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports.run = (client, message) => {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL)
  .setColor(3447003)
  .setDescription(`Owner: ${message.guild.owner.user.tag} (${message.guild.owner.id})`)
  .addField('Member Count', `${message.guild.memberCount - message.guild.members.filter(m=>m.user.bot).size} (${message.guild.members.filter(m=>m.user.bot).size} bots)`, true)
  .addField('AFK Timeout', `${message.guild.afkTimeout / 60} minutes`, true)
  .addField('AFK Channel', `${message.guild.afkChannelID === null ? 'No AFK Channel' : client.channels.get(message.guild.afkChannelID).name} (${message.guild.afkChannelID === null ? '' : message.guild.afkChannelID})`, true)
  .addField('Location', message.guild.region, true)
  .addField('Created', message.guild.createdAt.toLocaleString(), true)
  .addBlankField(true)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL);

  message.channel.send({embed});
};
```

and this is the error  code

```
client.commands.get('serverinfo').run(message, args)
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question! Besides that, I see you're using `RichEmbed`, which is [**outdated**](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-in-order). Instead, use `Discord.MessageEmbed()`

Answer (score 0):

It's best to start off coding discord bots by staying in the same file (index.js in most cases). As pointed out by @Toasty, `RichEmbed` is outdated in discord.js V12, [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html) is a link to syntax for `Discord.MessageEmbed()` in discord.js V12.